# Use of jQuery with multiple select on a same page that contain similar options to color

Tags: jquery, colors, multi-select

I want jQuery to change the color of some of my multi-select list's options to red, if a certain condition is selected. Here's my code:

```
$.each(subjects, function(key, subject) 
        {
            if (select.find('option[value=\"' + encodeURIComponent(subject) + '\"]').length === 0 && subject!="") 
            {
                   $('<option>', {
                     value: subject,
                     text: subject
                     }).appendTo(select);

                 if (colored==true)
                     {
                         //Change color of options' text
                         $("option[value='"+subject+"']").css('color', 'red');
                     }
            }
        });
```

The problem with this code, is that jQuery colors to red not only the options of the current multi-select on which it is working, which's name is defined in variable **select**. But jQuery also colors these options in all other multi selects on the page, if they contain it.

How to edit this code to make jQuery only color the option contained in the current multi-select, which's name is, again, defined in the **select** variable?

For instance, replacing

```
$("option[value='"+subject+"']").css('color', 'red');
```

with

```
(select.find("option[value='"+subject+"']").css('color', 'red');
```

did not work. What would be the correct code?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is the `select` variable coming from anyway?

Comment: The code given above is in a function. Here's how the function begins:
changeList = function(data, selectList, colored, emptyList)
  { 
      var subjects = data.split(',');
      var select = $('#'+selectList); [...]

Comment: Your solution looks like it SHOULD work. Something else must be going on. Can you build us a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see it failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try?

```
$("#" + selectList + " option[value='"+ encodeURIComponent(subject)+"']").css('color', 'red');
```

LMM - Edited to include the encode

Comment: @Blazemonger That's a pretty obvious mistake. Fixed it now.

Comment: @Blazemonger I have another question about this: my code does not paint in red options containing spaces. How can I solve this please?
(I can't reach Lee Meador with @ tag...)